# Display duplicate row info as extra column

Tags: mysql

I have three tables RESOURCES, SERVERS, ACTIVE_RESOURCES.  The HOSTED_RESOURCES table servers as a referential table to list which servers the resources are active on.  Currently I use the bellow query to retrieve a resource:

```
SELECT r.resource_id, r.serve_url, r.title, r.category_id, ar.server_id
FROM active_resources ar
LEFT JOIN resources AS r ON (ar.resource_id = r.id)
WHERE hr.resource_id = (
    select id from resources
    and id < 311
    order by date_added desc
    limit 1
);
```

Because in most cases the resources are available on all servers I end up with duplicate information in the query result, for example:

```
resource_id  | serve_url    | Title                 | category_id | server_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 309         | /b/7514.pdf  | Tuesdays with Morrie  | 1           | 1
 309         | /b/7514.pdf  | Tuesdays with Morrie  | 1           | 2
```

All of the data, except for `server_id` is a duplicate, so I was hoping to concatenate the result to one row displaying the server ids in additional columns, or even just list the server ids as comma separated in one column.

Thank you for looking at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT r.resource_id, r.serve_url, r.title, r.category_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(ar.server_id) AS server_id
FROM active_resources ar
LEFT JOIN resources AS r ON (ar.resource_id = r.id)
WHERE hr.resource_id = (
    select id from resources
    and id < 311
    order by date_added desc
    limit 1
)
GROUP BY r.resource_id, r.serve_url, r.title, r.category_id
;
```

Comment: Great, thanks!!!  This just dawned on me...  instead getting all of the server ids, is it possibly to randomly select just one?  The reason I'm asking is because once I have the available server ids, I randomly select them anyways in PHP.

Comment: Basically, selecting a random row is a concept, that is alien to a database. You can get a non-deterministic (but not random) server_id by replacing `GROUP_CONCAT(ar.server_id) AS server_id` by simply `server_id`.